# How navigate with drawer in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an application in which I have added a side navigation menu. I have also added the menu icon in the TopBar. When this button is pressed, the side menu is displayed with its options (Data and About).

I don't know how to achieve the following:

1. When I am in the Data window I want the TopBar icon to be the menu or hamburger icon
2. When in the About window I want the TopBar icon to be the back arrow
3. When you are in the About window and click on the back arrow of step 2, I want you to return to the Data window

With the attached code, I can navigate between the Data and About window, but I have no way to go back, except with Android's own button in the bottom bar. My intention is to be able to navigate with the TopBar button

MainActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    MainScreen(viewModel = viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(
        drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val navigationItems = listOf(
        Screen.DataScreen,
        Screen.SettingsScreen
    )

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = { TopBar(navController = navController, scope = scope, scaffoldState = scaffoldState) },
        drawerContent = { Drawer(scope = scope, scaffoldState = scaffoldState, navController = navController, items = navigationItems) },
        drawerGesturesEnabled = true
    ) {
        NavigationHost(navController, viewModel, params)
    }
}
```

TopBar:

```
@Composable
fun TopBar(
    navController: NavHostController,
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState
) {

    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                stringResource(R.string.app_name),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        },

        navigationIcon =
        {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                }
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu Icon")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Drawer:

```
@Composable
fun Drawer(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState,
    navController: NavHostController,
    items: List<Screen>
) {

    val currentRoute = currentRoute(navController)

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                    color = Color.White
                )
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_description),
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column {
                items.forEach { item ->
                    DrawerItem(item = item, selected = currentRoute == item.route) {
                        navController.navigate(item.route) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }

                        scope.launch {
                            scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DrawerItem(
    item: Screen,
    selected: Boolean,
    onItemClick: (Screen) -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { onItemClick(item) }
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
            imageVector = item.icon,
            contentDescription = item.title
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))

        Text(
            text = item.title
        )
    }
}
```

NavigationHost:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: MyViewModel
) {

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.DataScreen.route) {

        composable(Screen.DataScreen.route) {
            DataScreen(
                navController = navController,
                viewModel = viewModel
            )
        }

        composable(Screen.SettingsScreen.route) {
            SettingsScreen(
                navController = navController
            )
        }

    }

}
```

Screen:

```
sealed class Screen(
    val route: String,
    val title: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
) {

    object DataScreen :
        Screen("data_screen", "Data", Icons.Filled.LocationOn)

    object SettingsScreen :
        Screen("settings_screen", "About", Icons.Filled.Info)

}
```

Comment: sounds like you need different scaffolds for each of your screens instead of having one

Comment: If you are interested I have a solution which I can post tomorrow, where I will be in my office...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm interested, I look forward to it!